# @AliasFor doesn't work on attribute in custom annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations

I'm using SpringBoot 2.4.2. And I'm struggling with @AliasFor with custom annotation.

I implemented below custom annotation.

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface CustomAnnotation {

  @AliasFor("aliasAttribute")
  String value() default "";

  @AliasFor("value")
  String aliasAttribute() "";
}
```

And using it like this.

```
@CustomAnnoatation("test")
@Component
public class TestClass() {
 // codes here
}
```

And this test code fails.

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestClass.class)
public class CustomAnnotationTest {

  @Autowired
  TestClass testClass;

  @Test
  public void valueTest1() {
    Annotation annotation = testClass.getClass().getAnnotation(CustomAnnotation.class);

    assertThat(((CustomAnnotation) annotation).value()).isEqualTo(((CustomAnnotation) annotation).aliasAttribute());
  }
}
```

with message

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expecting:
 <"">
to be equal to:
 <"test">
```

I don't know why, anyone know?

Comment: Because you aren't using Spring to read the annotation thus it won't work. You will need to use the Spring annotation utils to read the annotation for proper support.

Comment: @M. Deinum Doesn't it happen while spring initializing beans? What the '@SpringBootTest' annotation does. Also this post didn't use Spring annotation utils. https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/spring-aliasfor-annotation-example/

Comment: Line 27 of the test in that sample clearly uses the `AnnotationUtils`.

Comment: yes, but it's 'findAnnotation' so I thought it was just used to find specific annotation. how about this? https://gist.github.com/SomboChea/0324964054c8269ce5f21e7f8ff4c01a
The full example of the code doesn't use any annotation utils.

Comment: That code doesn't because the bean is constructed by spring which internally uses that, if you would write a test you still need the `AnnotationUtils`.  Hence it still is used. Without using the spring capabilities for synthesized annotations you will not get the value for aliases because it is a spring feature.

Comment: I know that, and that's why I used @SpringBootTest annotation. However when I used it in my application code, it also didn't work. And that's why I wrote this test code. So are you saying it's natural that this test code fails?

Comment: Yes because you aren't using the spring infrastructure for obtaining a synthesized annotation. The `@SpringBootTest` doesn't make any difference, it will work the same without it and use `    Annotation annotation = TestClass.getClass().getAnnotation(CustomAnnotation.class);` both (your solution and this) totally bypass the spring facilities and thus won't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An annotation is static metadata for a class, field etc. so Spring cannot change anything about it. To make features as `@AliasFor` possible Spring uses, what they call, synthesized annotations. For those to be used/detected you need to utilize the Spring internals to obtain that synthesized annotation and for the `@AliasFor` to work. For this use `AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation` (Spring uses that internally as well).

`@AliasFor` is a Spring feature so without using the Spring components this won't work.

Your test method is basically the same as

```java
@Test
  public void valueTest1() {
    Annotation annotation = TestClass.class.getAnnotation(CustomAnnotation.class);

    assertThat(((CustomAnnotation) annotation).value()).isEqualTo(((CustomAnnotation) annotation).aliasAttribute());
  }
```

Both this test and your test will fail, because they simply don't use the Spring infrastructure for detecting annotations and apply the features of Spring.

When using `AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation` the test will pass.

```java
class CustomAnnotationTest {

    @Test
    void testStandardJava() {
        CustomAnnotation annotation = TestClass.class.getAnnotation(CustomAnnotation.class);
        assertThat(annotation.value()).isEqualTo(annotation.aliasAttribute());
    }

    @Test
    void testWithSpring() {
        CustomAnnotation annotation = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(TestClass.class, CustomAnnotation.class);
        assertThat(annotation.value()).isEqualTo(annotation.aliasAttribute());
    }
}
```

The `testStandardJava` will fail, the `testWithSpring` will pass because it uses the proper mechanisms.

Comment: hmm.. I thought Spring copies the value of one to another pair attribute of @Alisfor when it initializes beans but it doesn't seem to be. Thanks for your explanations.

Comment: No because that simply isn't possible. As stated in my answer annotations are static metadata. They cannot be changed at runtime.